# SSIS Insert values from dynamically created table into table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm using a SSIS script task to dynamically import and create staging tables on the fly from csvs as there are so many (30+.)

For example, a table in SQL server will be created called 'Customer_03122018_1305' based on the name of the csv file.  How do I then insert into the actual 'real' 'Customer' table?

Please note -there are other tables - e.g. 'OrderHead_03122018_1310' that will need to go into a 'OrderHead' table.  Likewise for 'OrderLines_03122018_1405' etc.

I know how to perform the SQL insert, but the staging tables will be constantly changing based on csv date timestamp.  I'm guessing this will be a script task?

I'm think of using a control table when I originally import the csv's and then lookup the real table name?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: create query based on table name and store that query in variable and use this variable in destination connection.

Comment: I've updated my original post  - how would I manage multiple different staging tables e.g. orderhead, order line etc.?

Comment: Don't use multiple staging tables. Use one per file type. Truncate, load, process each time. i.e. load the first Customer file into a table called staging.Customer, then merge it into the real customer, then truncate and repeat. It makes no sense to create an individual table per file.

Comment: What if I have many different csv's though - customer, orderhead, orderlines with different columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below process, to dynamically load all the staging tables to the main Customer table by using a FOR loop as stated below,

1. While creating the staging tables dynamically, store all the staging table names in a separate single variable separated by commas.
2. Also store the count of staging tables created in another variable.
3. Use FOR loop container and loop the container by the number of staging tables created.
4. Inside the FOR loop, use a script task and fetch the value of 1st staging table name into separate variable.
5. After the script task, inside FOR loop container, add a DataFlow task and inside it, build the OLEDB Source task dynamically by using the variable that is used to store the 1st staging table name in step - 4.
6. Load the results of from staging table to Actual table.
7. Remove the staging table name from the variable that is created i step - 1 (which contains all the staging table names separated by comma).

Comment: I've updated my original post  - how would I manage multiple different staging tables e.g. orderhead, order line etc.?

Comment: if the table schema changes, use a separate DataFlow task for OrderHead table.
If the number of staging tables created is different for OrderHead and Customer tables, then use a separate FOR loop, other wise use the same FOR loop with 2 different DataFlow tasks.

Note: Use a script task to identity the table name and route the flow to respective Data flow task inside the FOR Loop